# Parcelize annotation in AIDL: Incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to MyCustomObject

Tags: android, kotlin, parcelable, aidl, kotlin-android-extensions

I'm rewriting my model class to `Kotlin`, which has to be `Parcelable` and used in `AIDL`:

```
@Parcelize
data class MyCustomObject(val value1: String, val value2: String) : Parcelable
```

During compilation it crashes with error:

> error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to MyCustomObject

and points to this line in generated code:

```
if ((0!=_reply.readInt())) {
    _result = com.mypackagename.MyCustomObject.CREATOR.createFromParcel(_reply);
}
```

I used this annotation for other purposes and it was ok, only in AIDL I found mismatch so far.

Any ideas what's wrong?

EDIT: After 5 days with no single comment I've created [a ticket for this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110131003).

Comment: Did it work with java?

Comment: Also do you have MyCustomObject.aidl (the one that describes your data class?)

Comment: @IvanMilisavljevic, yes, it did. I have that object.aidl too.

Comment: sorry i'm still in java, my best guess there is something wrong with the parcelable generator and Kotlin data classes. One stupid suggestion did you try to clean and rebuild the project?

Comment: @IvanMilisavljevic, yeah, tried all in this manner. The problem is in annotation itself. Boilerplate parcelable in kotlin also works fine.

Comment: i see you have no responses to the ticket as well, can you please setup a simple example project for me to take a look?

Comment: @IvanMilisavljevic, in my profile there is a link to github. There is an old project InterProcessCommunication. You may add kotlin support for it and play with it if you like.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173230/discussion-between-yurets-and-ivan-milisavljevic).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a bug in Kotlin, so I redirected this issue to JetBrains.
You may track it here: [KT-25807](https://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/KT-25807).

This happens, because `createFromParcel()` does not return class `T`, but `Object`.

**UPD**

Parcelize annotation is now maintainable by Google and the issue has been fixed in kotlin version 1.5.+ https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/110131003

Comment: Any solution for aids with parcelized used in AIDL? Having same problem

Comment: Boilerplate implementation of Parcelable. This bug has no resolution so far even though priority was set 'high'...